# How to query URLField in Django

Tags: django, django-models, filter

I have a model which takes urls:

```
class LinkCT(models.Model):
    link_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    link_slug = models.SlugField(null=False,blank=False)
    link_title = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)
    link_desc = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    link_url = models.URLField(null=False, blank=False)
```

I am trying to filter rows which have same url in link_url field as below:

```
duplicateChk = LinkCT.objects.filter(Q(link_url = linkurl))
```

where linkurl is a variable which is catching post data of link_url. I already have some entries with same urls but it is returning blank list.

Is there a different way to filter URLField? I googled for it, but it seems I am the first one facing this problem or otherwise I am simply missing something trivial in code.

I tried from python manage.py shell, there also it returns blank list. However, I am able to filter with other non-url fields.

the url is:

```
http://www.google.com
```

or something like this. the variable

```
linkurl = request.POST['link_url'].
```

tried hard coding the value like

```
duplicateChk = LinkCT.objects.filter(Q(link_url = "http://www.google.com")),
```

but no success.

Comment: Can you paste a sample of a url you are trying to filter? (both the linkurl and the link_url entry.

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to expand on "variable which is catching post data of link_url". The query above will only work if "linkurl" is  equal to the entire url saved in the database.

Comment: also, you don't need to do this `filter(Q(link_url = linkurl))` you can just do `filter(link_url=linkurl)`

Comment: Can you hard-code the linkurl value to see if it's working? If it is, that means your data comes different than you expect from the POST.

Comment: the url is 'http://www.google.com' or something like this. the variable 'linkurl = request.POST['link_url']'. tried hard coding the value like 'duplicateChk = LinkCT.objects.filter(Q(link_url = 'http://www.google.com'))', but no success.

Comment: the url is http://www.google.com or something like this. the variable 'linkurl = request.POST['link_url']'. tried hard coding the value like duplicateChk = LinkCT.objects.filter(Q(link_url = "http://www.google.com")), but no success.

Comment: I have added more in code, since comments is not properly showing code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the url you're searching for is identical to the one in the database? Django's URLField normalizes urls on save, adding a slash to the end if it's just a domain. Does this work?

```
duplicateChk = LinkCT.objects.filter(link_url = "http://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: Yes!! it was trailing slash. while filling form, trailing slash is generally ignored and linkurl is fetching post data which was without trailing slash. Thanks for bringing to notice.